# .Net Core DI constructor list parameteres initialized with empty lists instead of null

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

Why when using .Net Core DI, IEnumerable parameteres in constructors initialize with empty arrays/lists?
Is there any ways to initialize it with nulls, except of writen lambda in ServiceCollectionExtenson.cs or edit SomeoneClass?

```
   public class SomeoneClass
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<string> _list;
        public SomeoneClass(IEnumerable<string> list = null)
        {
            _list = list; // <===== this is initialize with string[0] not a null
        }
    }

    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services, 
           IConfiguration configuration)
        {
             services.addScoped<SomeoneClass>();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Which .NET and C# version are you using? With nullable reverence types` IEnumerable<string>` explicitly asks for a *non*-null value. A `string[0]` is a perfectly valid value in that case. Besides, why are you using such code in the first place? If your class has a dependency, shouldn't you actually provide a valid value for it?

Comment: What's the actual question here? Why are you using `IEnumerable<string> list = null)` in a DI-registered class? What is the actual problem you tried to solve by using `null` as the default?

Comment: SomeoneClass is not my class and i cant edit it. Actualyy it is https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer. In constructor it compare this parameter with null and  if it is null it use default value. But with DI it not happens becouse this parameter is empty list but not null.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Why are you registering it without specifying all the parameters? Or why are you registering *that* class instead of one of your own that passes the items you want? And why `Scoped`? `HtmlSanitizer` doesn't implement `IDisposable`. Why register it at all?

Comment: [HtmlSanitizer is thread safe](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer#thread-safety) which means you can construct a single instance and register it as a singleton if you want.

Comment: I think (not sure) it's happening because you're using c# 8 or higher, where nullable reference types were introduced, and since the parameter isn't being explicitly declared as nullable, the DI engine must be injecting an empty list. But I don't understand why a registered class can be injected with null parameters.